# variable hitOrStick may not have been initialised

Tags: java, variables

I'm having an issue with this code its for a school task, when compiling it says

```
hitOrStick might not have been initialized
```

I have no idea what is causing it because I'm pretty sure It has been initialized, if you can spot any other mistakes it will be greatly appreciated.

(I know it is not real black jack it is very basic!) Thanks again.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.*; 

class blackjack

{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

int total;
boolean play;
int computerTotal = 0;
String hitOrStick;

System.out.println("You are playing BLACK JACK.");

    int card1 = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
    int card2 = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
    total = card1+card2;

    System.out.println("Card 1 value: "+ card1);
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Card 2 value: "+ card2);
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("You have: " + total);
    System.out.println(" ");

    if(total == 21)
        {
        System.out.println("Blackjack! Congratulations you have won!");
        }
    while(total < 21)
        {
        System.out.println("Would you like to hit or stick? please type 'H' or 'S'");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("If you type anything other than the options it will count as a STICK.");
        hitOrStick = scan.next();
        }   
        if(hitOrStick == "H")
            {
            int hitCard = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
            System.out.println("New Card value: "+ hitCard);
            total = total + hitCard;
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("You now have: " + total);
                if(total > 21)
                {
                System.out.println("YOU ARE BUST!");
                }
            }
            else
            {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("You have chosen to stick.");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("Your total is: " + total);
            computerTotal = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 20);
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("the computer has: " + computerTotal);
            }

            if (computerTotal > total)
            {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("COMPUTER WINS!");
            }
            else
            {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("YOU WIN!");
            }





}
}
```

Comment: put explicit null to your var. e.g. String hitOrStick=null;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare an initial value:

```
String hitOrStick = ""; // or null
```

The compiler doesn't interpret your code to make sure that the variable will be set to a value when it's used, it just points out that it might be possible.

In fact, if you're using Eclipse you can set your preferences such that this compiler error is just a warning or an ignored condition.

Comment: Or you could just click "Proceed" and watch if the program crashes.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help it worked but i'm stuck as to where i should end the while loop because atm its always asking for the H/S option

Comment: @user2233480 your while loop never ends. Look at the conditions: `while (total < 21)` but inside your loop, total is never affected. Did you want it to extend past your many if statements? Just move one }

Answer (score 1):

Compiler complains about your string var that has no initial value. Put explicit null to your var. 
e.g. 
`String hitOrStick=null;`

Answer (score 1):

In your code here:

```
int total;
boolean play;
int computerTotal = 0;
String hitOrStick;
```

Several variables have been named, but not initialized. It helps to initialize them all:

```
int total = 0;
boolean play = false;
int computerTotal = 0;
String hitOrStick = "";
```

By doing this, you are ensuring that less errors will happen.

---

Your error occurs because hitOrStick is named, not initialized, then later in the code, you have `if (hitOrStick == "H")` (this is not a good idea, better is `if (hitOrStick.equals("H"))`) which may be called while hitOrStick is still not initialized.

Comment: The initialization inside the loop would **definitely** persist past the loop. It has nothing to do with scope .  However if the first two cards produce **22** and the `while` loop never runs through it's body, then, in fact, there will be a comparison of uninitialized variable.